# Dart converting Firebase Object to Pojo Class

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am reading the Firebase documents as below

```
        collectionRef.get().then(
             (querySnapshot) {
               print("All Orders");
               for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
                
                 var _product = docSnapshot.data();
                 print(CartItem.fromJson(_product).company);
        
               }
             },
             onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
           );
```

The print statement is printing the value as List of object

[{quantity: 1, price: null, model: TP WM TWT95-P102GB, company: Choose Company, id: 2023-06-08 16:45:20.388836, title: null}, {quantity: 1, price: null, company: Choose Company, model: KD-65X75L   IN5, id: 2023-06-08 16:45:20.838656, title: null}, {quantity: 1, price: null, model: HM SAC  RAS222PCAIBA, company: Choose Company, id: 2023-06-08 16:45:21.499394, title: null}]

Now i want to convert it into Cart Item object using CartItem.fromJson

```
            CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
                : this(
                    id: json['id'] as String?,
                    title: json['title'] as String?,
                    quantity: json['quantity'] as int?,
                    price: json['price'] as double?,
                    company: json['company'] as String?,
                    model: json['model'] as String?,
                  );
```

It is showing the below error when i am trying to print the company attribute

```
            I/flutter (12337): All Orders
            I/flutter (12337): null
            I/chatty  (12337): uid=10091(com.example.ts) 1.ui identical 1 line
            I/flutter (12337): null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the data output of your `_product` to make sure you have the correct 'flat' data and that there is no object encapsulating your cart item info.

I personally write my factory like that if all of your fields are nullable.

```
  factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CartItem(
      quantity: json['quantity'],
      price: json['price']?.toDouble(),
      model: json['model'],
      company: json['company'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
```

It works fine on my side with this samples please provide more context/info if needed.